# g++ не видит библиотеки

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Запускаю g++ под ubuntu11.10

```
zhas@zhas-Aspire-5740:~/ma-source/gts/fann/src$ g++ gis_train.cpp -l "doublefann" -I "include/"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldoublefann
collect2: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

доказательство что файл на месте(doublefann.a):

```
zhas@zhas-Aspire-5740:~/ma-source/gts/fann/src$ dir
CMakeLists.txt  doublefann.o    fann_error.c  fann_train_data.c  gis_train.cpp
doublefann.a    fann.c      fann_io.c     fixedfann.c    include
doublefann.c    fann_cascade.c  fann_train.c  floatfann.c
```

потом попробовал прописать полный путь до либы

```
zhas@zhas-Aspire-5740:~/ma-source/gts/fann/src$ g++ gis_train.cpp -lhome/zhas/ma-source/gts/fann/src/doublefann -I "include/"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhome/zhas/ma-source/gts/fann/src/doublefann
collect2: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

далее я её пихнул в /usr/lib/ , и даже так не видит (((

помогите плз

p.s. попробывал на винде тем же g++, все работает, но мне нужно под убунту

Comment: Убрать пробел/кавычки в варианте 1? Поставить кавычки в варианте 2? Не хватает прав на чтение? Может попробовать сделать отдельно объектник из gis_train, а потом вместе слинковать? Или стоит написать makefile, раз файл не один. В гцц не мастер и линукса к сожалению нет под рукой.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда же вы пишите в командной строке опцию -l "smthng" (или как обычно пишут -lsmthng), вы говорите компилятору найти и прилинковать библиотеку [libsmthng.so](http://libsmthng.so) или libsmthng.a .  Компилятор ищет библиотеки в системных директориях по-умолчанию (обычно /usr/lib) и в директориях указанных опцией -L. Получается, в вашем случае надо переименовать doublefann.a в libdoublefann.a и компилировать так:

```
g++ gis_train.cpp -l doublefann -I "include/" -L.
```